# Overwrite existing JSON using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am using following JSON

```
{
  "Valuation": {

    "Occupancies": [
      {
        "ID": 0,
        "Code": 0,          
        "Height": 0,
        "Percent": 0
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

In this JSON I want to change 'Code' (which is inside occupancies) I want the value of code to be value stored in 'a'(the value 'a' is something I parse from csv file as shown below).
I am using following python code:

```
import json
import os
import csv
os.chdir('C:\\path\\to\\folder') # it is the path of *.JSON file 


    csv_file=open('Export_C.csv')
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
       a=row[3]             # 'a' stores the numerical data from csv file

    with open('add_location.json') as json_data:
       data = json.load(json_data)

       for Occupancies in data['Valuation']['Occupancies']:
          Code=data['Valuation']['Occupancies'][0]['Code']
          Height=data['Valuation']['Occupancies'][0]['Height']
          print(Code, Height)
```

Output is

```
0 0
```

How do I overwrite the 'Code' value in JSON with the value stored in 'a'? I want to overwrite JSON and save it with the new value.

Comment: have you tried `data['Valuation']['Occupancies'][0]['Code'] = a`?

Comment: You need to actually edit the `data` dictionary, then **overwrite** the JSON file. You're only opening the file for reading

Comment: I tried data['Valuation']['Occupancies'][0]['Code'] = a it adds the value. However when I open *.json under the path 'C:\\path\\to\\folder' the value in json not updated

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you that worked, I edited the dictionary and then exported the result into another *.json file